# How to scrape the particular field as shown in the below HTML code with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Here's the HTML code for email field:

```
<div class="forge-form-group forge-col-12"><label class="">Email</label><input class="forge-form-control" data-fieldname="email" name="email" type="email" value=""><small class="forge-form-text forge-text-muted">Haven't signed up?<a class="forge-ml-2" href="#">Create an account</a></small></div>
<input class="forge-form-control" data-fieldname="email" name="email" type="email" value="">
```

Here's my Python code:

```
email_cell=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='forge-form-group forge-col-12']//input[@class='forge-form-control']")
```

But the problem is that there's an identical field for the password too. It differs from the data-field name which is equivalent to password. Here's that HTML code snippet too:

```
<div class="forge-form-group forge-col-12"><label class="">Password</label><a class="forge-float-right" href="#">Forgot password?</a><input class="forge-form-control" data-fieldname="password" name="password" type="password" value=""></div>
```

Now I am super-confused about how to access these two fields individually. The page I am automating can be found here:
https://moz.com/login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath used in your sample is locating two fields -- Email and Password. This will not work for your code, because you are just trying to locate Email. The `//` notation in your XPath means the path is locating **any** field -- Email and Password happen to have the same containing `div` and `input` elements with the same `class` names you used. We need to use a unique attribute to locate each element -- in this case we can use the `data-fieldname` attribute to get the correct field.

It is also recommended to invoke `WebDriverWait` on the Email field to give the page sufficient time to load before attempting to locate and send keys to the element.

The following code sample should give you an idea of how to use these element attributes. This is an example of typing in email, password, and clicking log in on the page you provided -- I have run this locally successfully:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# add the above imports


driver.get("https://www.moz.com/login")

# wait for email field to exist
email_cell = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@data-fieldname='email']")))

# send keys to email field
email_cell.send_keys("myemail")

# locate password and send keys
password_cell = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-fieldname='password']").send_keys("mypassword")

# click log in
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Log in']").click()
```